# Crítica para quando for fazer o Deploy

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, webforms

No caso de uma aplicação webforms .NET que esta sendo feito um deploy, existe alguma forma de avisar ao usuário que o sistema esta sendo atualizado?

Comment: Faz um redirect, com a condição de que qualquer pagina que o usuário acessar ele cai na pagina de aviso, dizendo: "O sistema está sendo atualizado, aguarde uns instantes, bla bla".

Comment: Já tive uns contatos com o c# mas nunca fiz deploy na web. Eu uso PHP e NODEJS, um `.htaccess` resolveria meu problema

Comment: @GermanoSampaio, Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você está trabalhando com o `IIS` simplesmente adicione a sua página de manutenção com o seguinte nome `app_offline.htm`. Enquanto esse arquivo estiver na raiz do seu site todas as requisições serão redirecionadas para ele. Uma vez feito o deploy, remova o arquivo e o website voltará a responder com a sua aplicação.

Mas leve em consideração que no exato momento em que você publicar esse arquivo na raiz do seu site, a sua aplicação será parada e irá "derrubar" todos os usuários, sessões e variáveis de aplicação definidas em runtime.

A grande vantagem é que qualquer url requisitada será redirecionada para essa página.

> **Edit**
>
> Fazia muito tempo que eu não aplicava essa técnica e nunca havia
>   reparado que se o website for parado você receberá um erro 404 e
>   durante o recycle do pool, receberá um 503.
>
> Então se o resultado esperado for não exibir erros em hipótese alguma
>   para o usuário. Talvez seja necessário você disponibilizar em uma
>   outra estrutura a sua tela de indisponibilidade, usando o `app_offline.htm`, com um novo pool de aplicação e apontar esse
>   diretório com raiz do seu site, enquanto realiza o deploy da nova
>   versão.

Comment: Não entendi bem, toda vez que eu fizer o deploy, essa eu devo colocar essa página la?

Comment: Quando você coloca esse arquivo lá, todas as requisições serão respondidas com o conteúdo dessa página. Enquanto o pool estiver sendo reiniciado o site não irá responder. Porém para a substituição de arquivos além dos binários, é uma boa solução, evitando exibir mensagens de erro 500 e 404

Comment: Eu tenho q criar por fora da aplicação, é isso?

Comment: Isso é um arquivo html comum, você monta ele como quer que a tela seja exibida durante o seu processo de deploy. Faça um teste no seu iis local para ver

Comment: Deu certo aqui! Vlw @Leandro Angelo